# RTOS example where GPOS will most likely fail

Tags: rtos

I want to know a few application examples where one needs to use RTOS in order to ensure a working system.

I did some google search and whatever examples I found, I feel could be implemented using a windows or linux system.

Comment: One example from Wikipedia: "A common example of an RTOS application is an HDTV receiver and display. It needs to read a digital signal, decode it and display it as the data comes in. Any delay would be noticeable as jerky or pixelated video and/or garbled audio."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference between an RTOS and a GPOS is that an RTOS guarantees deterministic response.  That is to say that the worst case response time to an event is precisely bounded (and usually fast).  A GPOS schedules processes generally on "balanced load" basis - it assumes that all processes and events are of equal importance and will be allotted a "fair" share of processor resources.  For that reason when a process has the CPU, unless it yields "cooperatively" it will have sole use of the CPU for the duration of its time slot (assuming a single core - multi-core processors allow true concurrency, but the GPOS still allots the cores of a balanced load basis).  A time slot may be several tens of milliseconds, and the time taken to service a particular process will depend greatly on the number of processes simultaneously demanding CPU time.  Outside perhaps of implementing a kernel level driver, achieving timing constraints of a few tens of microseconds (or less) is not possible (or desirable) in a GPOS.

If your application is what Microsoft's marketing used to call *"soft" real-time* (i.e. not real time at all) that a GPOS may suit.  Linux can be built with "real-time" scheduling support, but it does not really make Linux suited to a large set of "hard" real-time tasks, and it is still "soft" in the sense that most of the time it will meet deadlines, but in some outlier conditions it may fail.  If that is your medical life-support system, you probably don't want to trust to that!

As an example of an attempt to run essentially real-time tasks on a GPOS that fails, years ago when MMX instructions were added to Pentium processors (running typically at 60MHz then), someone had the bright idea of "Host Signal Processing", a method applied to reduce the cost of PSTN modems (dial-up) by performing the signal processing on the PC rather than using a dedicated processor or DSP in the modem hardware - these "modems" were not really modems at all; they were telephone interfaces and digital converters for modem software.  At the time I worked for a company producing PSTN modem test equipment, and we tried one of these early HSP modems, and it worked right up until you launched Microsoft Word (or pretty much any large application), when it would instantly drop the connection.  Things improved as PCs became faster, but the point is that it was not guaranteed to work - it just *mostly* did.

Another example I have worked on is on a carton loading machine in food packaging.  The product is inserted into the carton, a glue stripe applied, and the closure folded.  The carton is moving continuously during this process an the timing of the glue gun is critical - for a glue stripe to be accurate to within one millimetre on a carton moving at one metre per second requires timing within one millisecond.

Another example is that of TDMA communication as used in digital telephony for example. Such communication allocates a time slot for each stations transmission and failure to transmit in exactly the correct time slot, or encroaching on the time slot of another station is unacceptable.  Such systems are globally synchronised to atomic-clock accuracy (typically derived from a GPS receiver). A GSM time slot for example is 577 microseconds, in this time, the transmitter must ramp-up the transmitter power, transmit the data and ramp-down

In short any example that requires 100 percent deterministic timing needs an RTOS. If your timing constraints are say > 100ms, and a small probability of failure to meet timing is tolerable, then a GPOS may work all or most of the time. If timing constraints are sub-millisecond or the cost or consequences of failure unacceptable, then an RTOS is appropriate.